# Overlap scrolling view with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to implement the 'Flexible Space with overlapping content' pattern from the [Material design scrolling techniques](https://material.google.com/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html), such as in [this video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsRVpzZG0zZGVNSXM/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_overlap_xhdpi_003.webm):
[image: Flexible Space with overlapping content GIF]

My XML layout right now looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="192dp"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <....>
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using the Design Library? Or do I have to build a custom [CoordinatorLayout.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) to do this?

Comment: I am searching for the oppositve, an image inside CollapsingToolbarLayout should show a few dps more after the toolbar and below the NestedScrollView in another color!

Comment: I was using FrameLayout, RelativeLayout but always the fragments were overlapped with the actionBar. Using a NestedScrollView as a parent for all of the fragments was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 154, accepted):

In fact, overlaying the scrolling view with the AppBarLayout is an included feature of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html): you can use the `app:behavior_overlapTop` attribute on your `NestedScrollView` (or any View using [ScrollingViewBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html)) to set the overlap amount:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">
```

Note that `app:behavior_overlapTop` only works on views that have the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` as it is the Behavior that is using the attribute (not the View or the Parent ViewGroup, as attributes usually apply to), hence the `behavior_` prefix.

Or set it programmatically via [setOverlayTop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html#setOverlayTop(int)):

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = ...
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) scrollView.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior =
    (AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior) params.getBehavior();
behavior.setOverlayTop(128); // Note: in pixels
```

Comment: This is almost working for me, except my RecyclerView (on which I've set the `layout_behavior` and `behavior_overlapTop`) ends up *behind* its sibling AppBarLayout. I've tried switching the order in the XML, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: When I disable scrolling (removing app:layout_scrollFlags attributes) - behavior_overlapTop doesn't work - NestedScrollView goes under AppBarLayout. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @PavelBiryukov what did you do for API < 21?

Comment: I have elevation - it works fine on both :) appcompat library handles android:elevation now
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="32dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        >

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work for me. I receive `error no resource identifier found for attribute behavior_overlayTop`

Comment: @Lynx - confusingly enough, it is `behavior_overlapTop` but `setOverlayTop()` - overlap vs overlay. Make sure you are using the right one!

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039075/2180405), call setTitleEnabled(false) on your CollapsingToolbarLayout to make the title stay fixed at the top as in the example.

Like this:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
```

or by adding it in xml like this:

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

Otherwise the title could disappear behind the overlapping content, unless of course, that's the behaviour you want.

Comment: You can put a large enough expandedTitleMarginBottom to the CollapsingToolbarLayout to avoid overlapping the title when expanded.