# Animating logo along with collapsing toolbar within CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to implement collapsible toolbar with a logo in the following manner:

1. Flexible Space with overlapping content, like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039074/overlap-scrolling-view-with-appbarlayout) (have this already);
2. Parallaxed pattern in this space that gets scrimmed with solid color (have this too)
3. A horizontally-centered logo, which must appear right above the content but float upwards as toolbar collapses:
   [image: mockup]
   In action it should be something like Pesto's leaves here (not necessarily resizable, but that would be a plus):
   [image: in motion]

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/random_pattern"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">

                <!-- card content -->

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is, wherever I try to place the logo picture, either it doesn't move like I need it too, or everything breaks. It feels like a custom Behavior might be required. Unfortunately **neither** of the tutorials I found on the new Design library explain how to extend it — only how to use provided stuff. There's no source code of it released, the decompiled code has no comments and is extremely tangled, and the fact that I'm not yet very comfortable with Android's layouting internals makes it even worse.

Please help?

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I sorta did it!

My solution is horrible, so I'll still be expecting for better ones :)

I went on and created a custom view `CollapsingLogoToolbarLayout`, which is a subclass of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The latter class is where title transition is taken care of — so in my subclass I placed the logic that changed properties of the logo view, namely its `translationY` based on "expanded-ness" fraction. [Gist with code is here](https://gist.github.com/Actine/e547f38e7805c807cd48). Now after I found suitable offset parameters, my layout looks like this:

```
...
<com.actinarium.random.common.CollapsingLogoToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"

        app:logoViewId="@+id/collapsing_logo"
        app:collapsedViewOffset="0dp"
        app:expandedViewOffset="-56dp">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/random_pattern"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/random_logo"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</com.actinarium.random.common.CollapsingLogoToolbarLayout>
...
```

[image: Recording]

Comment: Seems like I was celebrating too soon. For some reason this doesn't work on pre-Lollipop: the `FrameLayout` with logo is positioned far outside the screen (`getY()` is negative).

Comment: It doesn't work because Design library applies offset using `ViewOffsetHelper`, which relies on `TranslationY` only for API 22 for some reason. Obviously the class is package-local, thank you very much…

Comment: Do you have a solution for now?

Comment: @PavelBiryukov I decided to ditch `CoordinatorLayout` and related entities completely, and write all this "translate on scroll" logic myself. (and actually put this very app on hold in favor of another)

Comment: Actine, thx for reply! I asked Chris Banes - he said "No, we purposefully do not support that.  Because UX don't like the pattern."