# Collapsing Toolbar Like Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to implement a collapsing toolbar like google Play Store. I have achieved functionality somewhat but that is only working for portrait Screen. Here is a sample of screenshot of what i was able to do.

[image]

Now what i want to do is when i change my device orientation to LandScape mode it should look Exactly Like This.

[image]

So what my main question is how to handle these orientation changes. Is there any official android component available that can do this kind of thing or I will have to Z-index my Layouts to achieve this kind of Layout behavior. Please note that I want the layout to be exactly like this with Margins on Both Sides and Z-indexing on top of picture also the scrolling behavior needs to be exactly like Google Play Store.

I am attaching my sample xml that I have written so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <com.group3amd.materializeyourapp.widgets.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/FabStyle"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: In that case, you have to have separate layout for landscape mode. Introduce folder layout-land and then put the layout in this folder under the same name.

Comment: I have done that already but i want to know to Z-Index that layout so that it scrolls exactly like it does in Google Play Store.

Comment: [Here there is the answer to overlap AppBarLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31039075/4274296)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlap scrolling view with AppBarLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039074/overlap-scrolling-view-with-appbarlayout)

Answer (score 3):

In this pretty similar issue: [collapsing toolbar layout like google play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569824/collapsing-toolbar-layout-like-google-play-store), you would find an answer as below:

> View inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` no need to set
>   `app:layout_scrollFlags`. No effect. Base on my code,  change
>   `app:layout_scrollFlags` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to 
>   `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`  and
>   set `minHeight` for it.
>
> As your toolbar is `"pin"`, so `enterAlwaysCollapsed` will call it when
>   you scroll down.
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
>
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>         android:id="@+id/seffafCollapsingToolbarLayout"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="240dp"
>         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="164dp"
>         app:expandedTitleMarginStart="148dp"
>         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/header"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:src="@drawable/haber_icerik_resim"
>             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>             app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>             android:id="@+id/haber_toolbar"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>             app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
>             app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
>
>     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
>
> <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>     android:id="@+id/newsRecyclerView"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:scrollbars="vertical"
>     android:clickable="true"
>     android:background="@color/mainBackground"
>     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
> ```

In the comment to that post, you would find also a hint:

> add `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"` to your
>   collapsingtoolbarlayout. It is no need two toolbars to implement this
>   effect

EDIT: Here you would find an interview with a guy responsible for Google Play Store, he's talking about how he build design in Play Store App:

[[UDACITY] Interview with Kirill Grouchnikov, part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVC_ZmheVqw)

[[UDACITY] Interview with Kirill Grouchnikov, part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tcqz0aB2m38)

Hope it help

Comment: This is not what i want. Z Indexing does not work like it is shown in Landscape picture. It Doesn't Answer the Question

Comment: It does not answer the question.

Comment: I've added something what might help you with creating as you wish ;-)