# CollapsingToolbarLayout like PlayStore app

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to have the same behavior as the PlayStore app in terms of scrolling. Here is the gif of what I want to achieve https://giphy.com/gifs/MymB51M84gpdS.

What I have is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            style="@style/match"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                style="@style/match"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    style="@style/match"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv"
                    style="@style/matchwrap"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/matchwrap"
                    android:layout_above="@id/tv"
                    android:maxLines="2"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/match">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/match"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<FrameLayout>
<Button/>
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How do I achieve the PlayStore like scrolling behavior?

EDIT:
My question is more about when the screen is being pulled down, the `ToolBar` appears and then the image is shown. I want my behavior to match that.

Answer (score 0):

**Similiar question:** [collapsing toolbar layout like google play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569824/collapsing-toolbar-layout-like-google-play-store)

There is an `ImageView` with `parallax` collapseMode and of course, they pinned the `Toolbar` but after collapsing the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, `Toolbar` is going to be hide.

**Something like this:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/seffafCollapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: If you notice the PlayStore, when pulling down, the toolbar appears and when pulled more, the image then appears. I want more like that. Sorry my question was not clear. its edited now.

Comment: Did you see this answer from above link i've put? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34652303/4409113