# Scaling a View when using a Scroll View

Tags: android, view, scrollview

Building an app , i have this big scroll view and a calendar on top , the calendar is not part of the scroll view , i want when i scroll down that the calendar will be minimized and when i scroll up i want it to pop up or scale in height to its original size , what should i do ?

i dont really know any animations Technics in android and i assume this is not to hard to grasp.
i should consider listening to the scroll view events i guess and by that i can minimize the calendar view i guess....

please help.

Comment: check this one out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449871/collapsingtoolbarlayout-like-playstore-app

Comment: i guess thats one way to do a collapsing tool bar but my calendar is not a tool bar .. should it be ? hmm is there another way instead of adding it as a tool bar , so the same thing just for a view any kind of view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the calendar view inside collapsing toolbar layout and rest of the scrollable content inside the nested scrollview. It is the best way to do it.