# how to implement play store Collapsing Toolbar Layout?

Tags: android, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

*** It's not a duplicate of [collapsing toolbar layout like google play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569824/collapsing-toolbar-layout-like-google-play-store)**

I want to scroll collapsingToolbarLayout down when recyclerView scrolled down and vice versa like below .gif image.

Any help will be appreciated.

I used different layout_scroll flag but it does not work at all.

[image: image showing scrolling issue]

and there is xml layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/profileCoordinatorLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appBarLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileactivity_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

      </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </ir.unary.zhin.CAppBar>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

         </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SOLVED:***

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/main_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="156dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/subTitle" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/c1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and .gif image :

[image]

Please check and see if it works on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

to

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar_container">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Check this reference you will get idea how to achieve..**

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/material-design-tablayout-and-toolbar.html